# Problem with Metamask: We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

Problem with the development of a DAPP. Metamask says this: We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail.

This is my simple contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

pragma abicoder v2;

/**
 * @title ESGReport
 * @dev This contract implements a simple marketplace for ESG reports.
 */
contract ESGReport {

    address[16] public buyer;
    // Dichiarazione dell'evento ReportSold
    event ReportSold(
        uint reportId,
        address buyer,
        uint256 price,
        uint256 timestamp
    );

    

    /**
     * @dev Buys a report.
     * @param reportId The ID of the report to buy.
     */
    function buyReport(uint reportId) public payable {
        require(reportId >= 0 && reportId <= 20);
        buyer[reportId] = msg.sender;
        address payable publisherPayable = payable(0xF29CBD35Be47f53379Cd7226151eCeB470f5d00f);
        publisherPayable.transfer(msg.value);
        emit ReportSold(
            reportId,
            msg.sender,
            msg.value,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    /**
     * @dev Gets the list of published reports.
     * @return An array of Report structs.
     */
    function getBuyer() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
        return buyer;
    }

    /*
     * @dev Gets the owner of a specific report.
     * @param reportId The ID of the report.
     * @return The address of the report owner.
     */
    function getReportOwner(uint reportId) public view returns (address owner) {
        return buyer[reportId];
    }
}
```

I would like to understand where the error lies

Comment: Are you aiming to deploy the contract or to execute a specific function? If function, what input param values are you passing?

Comment: this error indicates that you are passing wrong arguments to the function.